# InvalidArgument=Value of '-1' is not valid for 'index'. Parameter name: index

Tags: c#, indexing, arguments

I'm getting "InvalidArgument=Value of '-1' is not valid for 'index'.
Parameter name: index". I'm don't which part I have messed up.

```
  private void bankerCard_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
   {
        e.DrawBackground();
        Brush myBrush = Brushes.Black;

        if (bankerCard.Items[e.Index].ToString().Contains("♥"))
            myBrush = Brushes.Red;
        else if (bankerCard.Items[e.Index].ToString().Contains("♦"))
            myBrush = Brushes.Red;
        else
            myBrush = Brushes.Black;

        e.Graphics.DrawString(((ListBox)sender).Items[e.Index].ToString(),
            e.Font, myBrush, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);

        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }
```

Above code tested, no problem. Problem happens below. any clue?

```
   private void playerCard_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawBackground();
        Brush myBrush = Brushes.Black;

        switch (e.Index)
        {
            case 0:
                myBrush = Brushes.Red;
                break;
            case 1:
                myBrush = Brushes.Orange;
                break;
            case 2:
                myBrush = Brushes.Purple;
                break;
        }

        e.Graphics.DrawString(((ListBox)sender).Items[e.Index].ToString(),
            e.Font, myBrush, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);  `error over here`

        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is self explanatory, probably here `e.Index` value is `-1` and you are trying to access `(ListBox)sender).Items[-1]`

```
((ListBox)sender).Items[e.Index].ToString()
```

To fix this you can add an if statement to check whether index is greater than -1:

```
if(e.Index >= 0)
{
   e.Graphics.DrawString(((ListBox)sender).Items[e.Index].ToString(),
        e.Font, myBrush, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault)
}
```